# Phasor and Vector in AC circuit

Tags: resistors, ac, reactance

Phasor is used to represent an AC quantity but for fixed frequency resistance and reactance of the circuit are not alternating but still they are represented by phasors. So is it right to call them phasors or they should be called something else like vectors or stationary phasors etc ?

Comment: A phasor is a stationary vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is it right to call [resistance and impedance] phasors?*

I call them "**complex numbers**".

To appreciate the difference, we should try to answer the question: "where do phasors come from?". They originate from our desire to use complex numbers to represent electrical quantities with sinusoidal amplitude and phase. It's easier to manage complex exponentials than it is to carry along sines, cosines with all their trigonometric hard-to-remember relations. So, we like to see a cosine as the real part of a complex exponential, like this:

$$ v(t) = v_p \cos(wt + \phi) = Re [ v_p e^{i (wt + \phi) }] = Re [ v_p e^{i  \phi} e^{i wt}] = Re[V_w e^{i wt}]$$

Now, if you are working with quantities oscillating all at the same frequency, you can 'forget' about the 'rotating' part \$e^{i wt}\$ and work with just the quantity

$$ V_w = v_p e^{i  \phi} = v_p \angle \phi $$

which is the **phasor**.
You should try to picture phasors as rotating vectors in the complex plane. Since you use them to describe sinusoidal steady-state systems, they all rotate with the same angular frequency and with the same relative phase.

So, you like to picture them on 'static' diagrams by simply 'rotating along with them' - that's why you do not include the 'rotating' part \$e^{i wt}\$.

When you picture voltage and current for a bipole, you know that they have the same frequency while their amplitude and phase are related by V = Z I. Where V and I are *phasors*, and Z is a *complex number* that changes the amplitude and the phase of one with respect to the other.

Z is NOT a phasor. It is not 'rotating'. It's a complex number. 
In the 'static' diagram where you rotate with the V and I phasors so that they appear as static 2D vectors (thus representable as complex numbers), you only need a complex number to change amplitude and phase from I to V. This is basic complex algebra: in y = z x where z and x are complex numbers, y is a complex number whose amplitude is the product of the amplitudes of z and x, and whose phase is the sum of their phases.

You might then wonder why if in the 'static representation' V and I and Z are all representable by complex numbers, Z cannot share the same 'rotating factor' as V and I. The reason is that when you add 'rotating' factors Exp[i w t] to your V = Z I *equation*, you want to add it only once per side so that its simplification justifies its disappearance. And since it is already associated with V on the lhs and with I to the rhs, you should not add it Z (which will be 'just' a complex number).

You should try to see what happens if you add a third (identical) rotating factor to Z.

Comment: so it means that phasor represents the rotating quantity while polar represents a non rotating quantity? right @sredni vashtar.

Comment: I don't see it this way. The polar form is just one of the ways to represent a complex number. Impedance is a complex number and can be represented in polar form. V and I (which according to the above notation I should call \$V_w\$ and \$I_w\$ ) are phasors and, being complex quantities, can still be represented by complex numbers in polar form. Their 'implicit rotating part' comes from other considerations which I believe I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**A  “Phasor” means a phase & vector amplitude** and can be rotating to illustrate an AC Voltage in time or fixed for some complex impedance to show magnitude and phase angle or a current peak phase or a voltage peak

Comment: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/phasors.html

Comment: reactance is not alternating for a fixed frequency? right ?

Comment: no but current can be

Comment: so phasor can be used to represent a fixed quantity as well.

Comment: it can be rotating current of fixed impedance or fixed current in time at peak

Comment: @Alex: Phasors only make sense when the frequency is fixed. If you have to consider different frequencies in a circuit, you either have to calculate it for some frequencies which are most interesting to you or let the computer do it: fourier analysis.

Comment: since current is proportional to voltage so the ratio of peak value of voltage to the peak value of current (Vp/Ip) will always give us the constand value of reactance and the phasor also represent that constant value.

Comment: The phasor has a length **and an angle**. If you say *represent that constant value*, you are dismissing the angle.

Comment: **if you say phasor, that always means both vector magnitude and phase angle.**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an example would help. If I have a voltage that is sinusoidal over time:
$$ v(t) = v_p \cos(wt + \phi) $$
I want to represent it as a phasor for steady state analysis (there may be a RMS factor in there depending convention):
$$ V_w = v_p \angle \phi $$
Notice that the phasor representation has no time dependency (stationary over time).

A main reason for doing phasor analysis is to remove the time dependency during such analysis. And it is easy to convert back and forth between the phasor representation (e.g. \$V_w\$) and its underlying time-dependent alternating quantity (e.g. \$v(t)\$).